# Reducing download time using prime numbers

Tags: probability, prime-numbers, factorial

An issue has cropped up recently in programming with which I could greatly benefit from the expertise of proper mathematicians. The real-world problem is that apps often need to download huge chunks of data from a server, like videos and images, and users might face the issue of not having great connectivity (say 3G) or they might be on an expensive data plan.

Instead of downloading a whole file though, I've been trying to prove that it's possible to instead just download a kind of 'reflection' of it and then using the powerful computing of the smartphone accurately reconstruct the file locally using probability.

The way it works is like this:

1. A file is broken into its bits (1,0,0,1 etc) and laid out in a predetermined pattern in the shape of a cube. Like going from front-to-back, left-to-right and then down a row, until complete. The pattern doesn't matter, as long as it can be reversed afterwards.
2. To reduce file size, instead of requesting the whole cube of data (the equivalent of downloading the whole file), we only download 3 x 2D sides instead. These sides I'm calling the reflection for want of a better term. They have the contents of the cube mapped onto them.
3. The reflection is then used to reconstruct the 3D cube of data using probability - kind of like asking a computer to do a huge three-dimensional Sudoku. Creating the reflection and reconstructing the data from it are computationally heavy, and as much as computers love doing math, I'd like to lighten their load a bit.

The way I'm picturing is like a 10x10 transparent Rubik's cube. On three of the sides, light is shone through each row. Each cell it travels through has a predetermined value and is either on or off (either binary 1 or 0). If it's on, it magnifies the light by its value. If it is off, it does nothing. All we see is the final amount of light exiting each row, after travelling through the cube from the other side. Using the three sides, the computer needs to determine what values (either 1 or 0) are inside the cube.

At the moment I'm using normal prime numbers as the cell values to reduce computing time, but I'm curious to know if there is another type of prime (or another type of number completely) that might be more effective. ***I'm looking for a series of values that has the lowest possible combination of components from within that series.***

Here is a rough diagram:

[image]

It might help to imagine that light shines in at the green arrows, and exits with some value at the red arrows. This happens for each row, in each of the three directions. We're left with only three 2D sides of numbers, which are used to reconstruct what's inside the cube.

If you look where the 14 exits on the left, it can have two possible combinations, (3 + 11 and 2 + 5 + 7). If for arguments sake we were to assume it were 3 and 11 (coloured green), then we could say at the coordinate where 3 and 11 exist, there are active cells (magnifying the light by their value). In terms of data, we would say this is on (binary 1).

In practice we can rarely say for certain (for 2 and 3 we could) what an inside value has based on its reflection on the surface, so a probability for each is assigned to that coordinate or cell. Some numbers will never be reflected on the surface, like 1, 4 or 6, since they can't be composed of only primes.

The same happens in the vertical direction, where the output is 30, which has multiple possibilities of which two correspond to the possibility shown in the horizontal direction with an exit of 14, coloured blue and pink (since they hit the 23, the same as 3 in the horizontal direction).

This probability is also added to that coordinate and we repeat in the front-to-back direction, doing the same a final time. After this is done for each cell in the whole cube, we have a set of three probabilities that a cell is either on or off. That is then used as the starting point to see if we can complete the cube. If it doesn't 'unlock' we try a different combination of probabilities and so forth until we have solved the 3D Sudoku.

[image]

The final step of the method is once the cube is solved, the binary information is pulled out of it and arranged in the reverse pattern to how it was laid out on the server. This can then be cut up (say for multiple images) or used to create a video or something. You could *cough* in theory *cough* download something like Avatar 3D (280GB) in around 3 minutes on decent wifi. Solving it (nevermind building the pixel output) would take a while though, and this is where I'm curious about using an alternative to prime numbers.

You might have guessed that my maths ability goes off a very steep cliff beyond routine programming stuff. There are three areas of concern / drawbacks to this method:

1. it is rubbish at low levels of data transfer. A 10 x 10 x 10 cube for instance has a larger 'surface area' than volume. That's because while each cell can hold one bit (either 1 or 0), each surface cell needs to be a minimum of 8 bits (one character is one byte, or 8 bits). We can't even have 'nothing', since we need null to behave as a type of placeholder to keep the structure intact. This also accounts for why in the above diagram, a 1000x1000x1000-cell cube has its surface areas multiplied by 4 characters (the thousandth prime is 7919 - 4 characters) and the 10'000(cubed)-cell cube has its surface areas multiplied by 6 characters (10'000th prime is 104729, six characters). The aim is to keep total character length on the 2D side to a minimum. Using letters could work, as we could go from a-Z with 52 symbols, before paying double bubble for the next character (the equivalent to "10"). There are 256 unique ASCII characters, so that's the upper limit there.
2. the factorials are still too high using prime numbers. Is there a series of numbers that are both short in character length (to avoid the problem above) and have very few possible parents? I'm leaning towards some subset of primes, but lack the maths to know which - some sort of inverted Fibonacci? The fewest possible combinations, the faster the computer will solve the cube.
3. I haven't tested yet if its possible to use a third, fourth or nth side to increase either the capacity of the cube or the accuracy of the reflection. Using a say octahedron (yellow below) instead of a cube might be better, just hurts the brain a little to picture how it might work. I'm guessing it would tend towards a sphere, but that's beyond my ability.

[image]

EDIT:

Thank you for your helpful input. Many answers have referred to the Pigeonhole principle and the issue of too many possible combinations. I should also correct that a 1000 x cube would require 7 digits not 4 as I stated above, since the sum of the first 1000 primes is 3682913. I should also emphasise the idea isn't to compress in the common sense of the word, as in taking pixels out of an image, but more like sending blueprints on how to build something, and relying only on the computation and knowledge at the receiving end to fill in the blanks. There is more than one correct answer, and will mark correct the one with the most votes. Many thanks for the detailed and patient explanations.

Comment: I know as much about the subject that you are broaching as I do about life on the planet Neptune.  Given that, from a black box perspective, it seems that image compression has already been studied with respect to storing graphics as "jpeg" files (e.g. \*.jpg).  The idea is that typical graphic software allows you to specify the *level* *of* *compression* that will be used to store the *.jpg file.  The greater the compression, the more data is lost and the smaller the file size.  So, if you could study the jpeg compression algorithm, you might be able to **avoid re-inventing the wheel.**

Comment: I hear what you're saying re the wheel (and practically I'd like to use it for image and video transfer) but in theory the same method could be used for any binary data, like texts, as long as it could be reconstructed at the other side. A jpg is transferred at full whack (say x MB), and ready to go upon arrival. We want to transfer at say x/n MB, and then reconstruct upon arrival.

Comment: As an aside, the probabilities aren't calculated on the fly for any given row - instead the exit value of a row is used to as a key to unlock a dictionary of array of probabilities, which is then is applied to the whole row at once. They are loaded ahead of time (and will always be the same) keeping computation to solving the cube only.

Comment: X-ray tomography tries to do this, although it can't choose to replace densities with prime numbers etc. The Radon transform is relevant.  But if the original data contains 1000 bits, then the transmitted data needs to say which of the $2^{1000}$ possible images it is, so the transmitted data needs 1000 bits as well.  Compression comes because neighbouring pixels in actual images are overwhelmingly similar to each other, so near enough is good enough.

Comment: Yes, just like an X-ray! But with unique values for each of the bones or whatever it passes through. Sorry, I don't follow the 2 to the power of 1000 thinking. A 1000-bit cube would have a reflection of 3 sides of 10x10 - at that level it would cost more to transfer the reflection that just the original binary (10(width) x 10(height) x 3(sides) x 8(bytes per character) x 2(characters) = 4800bits). I need to look up Radon transform.

Comment: A basic observation: There are $2^n$ different bit strings of length $n$. If your algorithm compresses every string of length $n$ down to some smaller length $m$, then it has (far) fewer possible output strings to use than the number of possible inputs, so many input files will have the *same* compressed representation, so the decompression procedure has no way to distinguish them.

Comment: It might be worthwhile to look into principal value decomposition, I think it sounds spiritually related to what you propose. Say you have $N$ pixels which are each grayscale, then the space of all such images can be modeled as an $N$ dimensional real vector space. The image is a point in this space. The idea of principal value decomposition is, given some large set of images, to identify a small number ($<< N$) of basis vectors in this pace which capture most of the variation of the data in the image. Projecting each image into this subspace is effectively a form of compression.

Comment: There is a minimum information content to a file. You fundamentally cannot compress it below this content level. File compression works because most files are highly redundant: the actual information content is far smaller than the file size. But just recognize that there is a limit, and there are algorithms out there that get reasonably close to it. you will only be able to beat them by small amounts. With images and sound, you can often go a little further by allowing some loss of information without noticable degradation of the image/sound quality ("lossy algorithms"), depending on the use.

Comment: I have a feeling this is not efficient in an information-theoretic sense.

Comment: to elaborate on what @Karl posted, I think that this implies all strings of a certain bit length have some upper bound on their kolmogorov-chaitin complexity which is definitely not true, some strings will require more bits than are being made available ipso facto this cannot work. I think even more simply you could just show that there's no injective function from binary strings of length n to binary strings of length n-1

Comment: I haven't voted on this, but if I did, I'd be tempted to downvote because of two things: (1)  the question suggests you're completely unaware of some basic principles of information theory (e.g. pigeonhole principle) that would prevent this from working as well as you seem to think it would (2) it also suggests you _really think_ you can beat the performance of other compression algorithms with this approach. To me, that suggest a certain level of arrogance and disdain for existing expertise in this area. I'm sure you didn't intend for it to come across that way, but to me it does.

Comment: (cont.) If your question had been written in a way that suggests someone seeking to understand, e.g. along the lines of "I'm not familiar with how real compression works, so I don't understand what would go wrong with this; can you help me understand?", then I would get entirely the opposite impression. Anyway, since you asked, I thought you'd appreciate this perspective on why a person _might_ downvote your question. (And yes, I get that my thinking is different from many other people who consider this a good question; that's okay, I'm not trying to argue right vs wrong voting.)

Comment: You may want to look at [interlacing](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Interlacing_(bitmaps))  The approach of those algorithms is similar enough to what you are doing that you may be able to borrow from them.

Comment: This also reminds me a bit of [turbo codes](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Turbo_code) which were build with the goal of maximizing channel bandwidth.

Comment: @DavidZ I apologise to you and anyone else of the impression it was an arrogant question to ask or worded arrogantly. That's wasn't my intention at all, I'm genuinely interested in getting feedback from people who know more than me in this area and tried to write it that way.

Comment: @DavidZ  Conceptually we might be going past one another on the topic of compression. The idea isn't to take data and remove the redundancy and transfer that, it's to be agnostic of the data (the content itself) and use just enough hints about its structure to be able recreate it at the other side. We're transferring building plans, not the building materials. Admittedly building plans with lots of pages missing where the foreman has to guess a bit before starting.

Comment: Another basic observation: if your algorithm could reduce any bit-string of length n to length m < n, then repeating the algorithm multiple times would eventually lead to reducing every input to 1 bit

Comment: I might be wrong, but this seems a bit too open-ended to have a concrete answer and seems better suited to open-ended discussion or research (which aren't particularly well-suited to the Q&A format of this site). Although compression, and video compression specifically, are well-studied fields. The only way you're likely to beat what's already out there is to very effectively target specific patterns that commonly exists in real-world data. Maybe your idea can do that, but at the moment you seem to be trying to build some general-purpose theoretical algorithm, which seems futile.

Comment: @BlueRaja-DannyPflughoeft lol that would be funny. I don't know if the information is really lost though as it descends into one bit. It becomes more reliant on the rules that create it (the ones building it in the computer). π is 1 byte but you can extrapolate a lot from it, if you know how to read it. Practically though small cubes are useless though and a 3x3 cube couldn't sufficiently hold enough information about itself to reconstruct itself. The 9 bits in the cube could only recreate one letter, so there's a lower limit.

Comment: A different approach you could look into to solve the problem is take advantage of the fact that every device that wants to download something already has several gigabytes of data on it which is universally known: the operating system. If you could index that data, then parts of the download could be made up of references to the known data, and be reconstructed. The issues would be having to have different versions of the file for each client OS, and having to create new versions when OS updates are released.

Comment: @AaronF that's a cool concept - like a library stored on every device we can mine for more data?

Comment: Note that the video most people is exposed to is already quite heavily compressed. The uncompressed video size would be probably a few dozen times as big as the video you actually receive on somewhere like Netflix or on a disc you purchase. Trying to compress already-compressed video would be a bad idea (and probably isn't even possible with your idea). You'll need to start from the uncompressed video and not only make something that can match or beat those existing compression ratios, but also do so while still having the video look decent. That's not going to be easy, to say the least.

Comment: @BernhardBarker the cube idea is agnostic to what it is "compressing". If it worked it would reconstruct the video in its already compressed format. It just takes the binary, and passes that along - it doesn't change any ones or zeros.

Comment: @JohnnyRockex I realise it can be used for any type of data, but cube-based compression would only be effective if the algorithm targets patterns that exists in your data when it's represented as a cube. There are definitely some such patterns in uncompressed video (but it may not be the patterns you want); there probably aren't such patterns in already-compressed video, which you may just turn into gibberish instead. Lossy compression for already-compressed data is a bad idea in general, because the more you compress, the more data you lose (and for lossless it usually just doesn't compress).

Comment: I'm not trying to dissuade you, in case it comes across as such, but rather I'm just trying to make sure you have an accurate idea of what's already out there, some of the basics of the theory of compression, what results you could actually expect and how much work you probably have to put in to get an algorithm that can compete with what's out there. Compression is an interesting topic, but if you're serious about it, I would suggest starting with investigating existing research on the topic. Of course if you're just experimenting with compression for fun, that's totally fine too.

Comment: @JohnnyRockex exactly :-) It's an idea that I had a few years ago but haven't gotten around to developing a PoC. It might not actually work very well in practice, and wouldn't work at all in the example you gave of the 280GB video file (operating systems are only 5 to 15 gigabytes or so), but for certain types of data it could be good. It could also have very strange drawbacks - downloading data to, say, Windows might be only 2MB but to Android might be 2GB - and OS updates might cause major headaches. But it might be worth investigating if you have time?

Comment: The answers below show you can't send plans with a unique solution using less bits (because code is nothing but plans in the first place!), but you could send incomplete plans. if you force the foreman to guess at every other bit, then the target phone could list sqrt(2^n) different files, and let the user/phone sort out which one they wanted. But note that if you're already using suitable compression too then each of those files is going to be reasonable, many will do *almost* what you wanted. The phone/usr won't be able to find the intended file without more hints, those hints take data.

Comment: I did not vote either since I did not want to downvote a question with so much context and effort. But as pointed out by someone else, it is not utterly absurd to downvote such a post. What could be improved : $(1)$ more focus on the suggested method/algorithm $(2)$ A justification why prime numbers should help to improve compressing (this is far from obvious) $(3)$ A comparison with the new method with methods being already available

Comment: "sending blueprints on how to build something, and relying on the computation and knowledge at the receiving end to fill in the blanks" **is compression in the traditional sense**

Comment: @user253751 I'm differentiating it from compression that actually goes into the binary and rearranges it to remove redundancy. Yes, both use blueprints to reconstruct, but the above method only uses blueprints. It fails conceptually though.

Comment: @JohnnyRockex you may have a bad understanding of how compression works, then - there is no such thing as "rearranging it to remove redundancy" and there is also no such thing as "going into the binary"

Comment: @user253751 If we optimise an image for web, does the binary change?

Comment: Your last comments reveal clearly that you know practically nothing about compression. Compression has nothing to do with binary, or optimization for web, or removing redundancy. You would do well to learn basic combinatorics followed by basic information theory, instead of continuing to repeat your claim that your question is not about compression, when it clearly is no matter what you think or say.

Comment: @user21820 I am assuming that the binary of an image before optimisation (e.g. 4mb) and after optimisation (e.g. 0.5mb) cannot be identical, since the total number of bits is heavily reduced.

Comment: I don't know why you seem to believe my above comment is wrong. Your comment after that only serves to confirm what I said.

Comment: @user21820 firstly, just because there is an internet between us doesn't mean we can't be amicable gentlemen or ladies. Secondly, if you are steadfast that the underlying binary doesn't change, how then does optimisation affect file size at the most granular level?

Comment: How can I even answer your 'questions' when they are simply meaningless? I say again; you need to learn basic combinatorics and basic information theory, otherwise you are just wasting your time and other people's time.

Comment: I'm not sure we're talking about compression anymore. Let's put a pin in it, but thank you for the input. Honestly, I appreciate discussing with and learning from others, and it's a great platform for that - I will check out those areas of study and keep researching.

Answer (score 49, accepted):

Universal lossless compression is impossible, this cannot work. The set of binary strings of length $n$ is not injective to the set of binary strings of length $n-1$.

There are $2^{n}$ binary strings of length $n$. Let us call the set of all binary strings of given length $S_{k}$. When $k=n-1$, there are $|S_{n-1}| = 1+2+2^{2}...+2^{n-1}=2^{n}-1$

Since $2^{n} > |S_{n-1}|$, the pidgeon hole principle implies that there is no injective function from the set of all binary strings of length $n$ to any $S_{k}$ for $k<n$. This means that a perfect lossless compression scheme such as the one described is an impossibility since it would constitute such a function.

Furthermore, for any number $n$ there exists a string of length $n$ whose Kolmogorov-Chaitin complexity is $n$.

If you assume this is not the case you have some function $g:P \to X$ where $p_{x} \in P$ is a program encoding a string $x \in X$ whose complexity $C(x)<|x|$. such that $g(p_{x})=x$ and$|p_{x}|< |x|$. We also know that $x \neq y \implies p_{x} \neq p_{y}$. Again by the pigeon hole principle if all $2^{n}$ strings of length $n$ have a program whose length is less than $n$, of which there can only be $2^{n}-1$, there must be a program that produces two different strings, otherwise the larger set isn't covered. Again this is absurd, so at least one of these strings has a complexity of at least its own length.

**Edit:** To questions about lossy compression, this scheme seems unlikely to be ideal for the vast majority of cases. You have no way of controlling where and how it induces errors. Compression schemes such as H.264 leverage the inherent visual structure of an image to achieve better fidelity at lower sizes. The proposed method would indiscriminately choose a solution to the system of equations it generates, which would likely introduce noticeable artifacts. I believe that it's also possible for these systems to be overdetermined, using unnecessary space, whereas a DCT is an orthogonal decomposition.The solution of these equations would also probably have to be found using a SAT/SMT solver, whose runtime would also make decompression very costly if not intractable, while DCT based techniques are well studied an optimized for performance, though I am not an expert on any of these subjects by any means.

Answer (score 27):

Full credit for an excellent question on which you have spent a lot of creative energy. This is a comment rather than an answer because it is too long for the usual comment box.

You have an interesting idea and please do continue to investigate it, but did you know data compression has a very wide research base already?  You may want to investigate in case your idea, or something similar, is already available.  There is a [Wikipedia article](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Data_compression) on compression as an entry point to the subject.

A few observations are:

1. Sound, movie and picture files in use by most applications are all highly compressed, usually (but not always) using imperfect algorithms with an associated loss of data.  Formats like zip, jpeg, mp3, mov and even png, are therefore not 'ready to go on arrival' but need sometimes extensive processing before use.  Algorithms have developed a lot over the last 50+ years and in some cases are highly sophisticated.
2. In general, compression exploits regularity in the original data (like a photo, where large parts of the image may be similar, or text where the message may only use a small number of different words) and works less well or not at all when file data are truly random.
3. In some applications, data loss can be acceptable, for example in a picture or in music where the eye or ear cannot really see or hear small imperfections, and in these cases very high levels of compression can be obtained (e.g. 90% reduction in size).  But for many purposes you need guaranteed perfect results as loss of accuracy simply won't be acceptable, for instance in a computer program file or in text. The data can often still be compressed, exploiting existing regularity, but a saving is not guaranteed in every case.

A final comment on these observations is that applying compression twice is rarely effective because regular data once compressed becomes much less regular and so less susceptible to further compression, so trying to compress a jpg or mp3 file will not usually save anything and may even cost space.

Comment: Thanks for your response. I imagine most optimisation is intelligent, as in for an image of a blue sky say, it might look for that regularity in the form of similar blue pixels, and if from say coordinates (0,0) to (1000,0) it's all blue, cut it. The cube method above is comparatively dumb, or apathetic. If it were used for that blue sky, it's not "taking any pixels out" (lossless), so it could be run on an already optimised image. The heavy lifting is the processing power to "guess" the data. It's not optimising the image in that sense, more capturing a shadow of its data and rebuilding it.

Comment: I would suggest either linking to, quoting, or paraphrasing [this section](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Lossless_compression#Limitations) as it is directly relevant to what OP is trying to accomplish.

Comment: I think this is a great answer to this question, but it might be worth pointing out that the most commonly used compression algorithms on the web are well-known not to be optimal and have existing successors, but JPG, PNG, MP3, MP4, etc are commonly supported and well-known so people stick with them.

Comment: It sounds to me like the idea here is you make the cube then have some sort of AI trained to guess the filling. (In other words, the exact _cube_ shape is not so relevant to the core idea as it is having the AI to guess the rest of the data given a part. One could just as well just lop out every other byte, say, and then do the same [that's 50% compression].)

Comment: The extra information, then, is in the AI's neural net.

Comment: +10 if I could. Not to forget that a widely used algorithm is Deflate, which renders combinations like compressing (compressed) PDF and PNG files with gzip or PKZIP-2 pretty useless, as they all use Deflate.

Answer (score 21):

I'll start off by confessing that I didn't read the entire description of your compression scheme in detail.  I don't really need to, since what you're trying to accomplish is an input-agnostic lossless data compression scheme, and that's impossible.

> **Theorem 1:** There is no lossless compression scheme that maps every file of length $n$ bits to a file of length less than $n$ bits.

The proof follows easily from the [pigeonhole principle](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Pigeonhole_principle) and the fact that there are $2^n$ distinct files of $n$ bits but only $2^n-1$ distinct files of less than $n$ bits.  This implies that any compression scheme mapping $n$-bit files to files of less that $n$ bits must map at least two input files to the same output file, and thus cannot be lossless.

> **Theorem 2:** There is no lossless compression scheme for which the average length of the output files is shorter than the average length of the input files (with averages taken over all possible input files at most $n$ bits long, for any non-negative integer $n$).

This stronger theorem is slightly trickier to prove. To keep it short, I'll assume you're familiar with basic set-theoretic notation, such as $R \cup S$ for the union, $R \cap S$ for the intersection and $R \setminus S = \{x \in R : x \notin S\}$ for the difference of the sets $R$ and $S$.

We do need a bit of extra notation.  Specifically, let $\operatorname{len}(x)$ denote the length of the file $x$, and let $\operatorname{len}(S) = \sum_{x \in S} \operatorname{len}(x)$ denote the summed total length of all files in the set $S$.  Thus the average length of files in $S$ is $\frac{\operatorname{len}(S)}{|S|}$, where $|S|$ is the number of files in $S$.  Also $\operatorname{len}(R \cup S) = \operatorname{len}(R) + \operatorname{len}(S)$ for any two disjoint sets of files $R$ and $S$.

Now let $f$ be a lossless compression scheme, i.e. a function mapping files to files, let $A$ be the set of all files of length at most $n$ bits, and let $B = \{f(x) : x \in A\}$ be the set of files obtained by applying $f$ to each file in $A$.  Since $f$ is lossless, it must map each input file in $A$ to a distinct output file; thus $|B| = |A|$, and thus also $|A \setminus B| = |B \setminus A|$.

Since $A$ is the set of all files at most $n$ bits long, it follows that $\operatorname{len}(x) ≤ n$ if and only if $x \in A$.  Thus $$\operatorname{len}(A \setminus B) ≤ n \cdot |A \setminus B| = n \cdot |B \setminus A| ≤ \operatorname{len}(B \setminus A)$$ (where the second inequality is strict unless $A = B$, implying that $A \setminus B = B \setminus A = \emptyset$).

Furthermore, since $A \cap B$ is disjoint from both $A \setminus B$ and $B \setminus A$, $$\begin{aligned}\operatorname{len}(A) &= \operatorname{len}(A \cap B) + \operatorname{len}(A \setminus B) \\ &≤ \operatorname{len}(A \cap B) + \operatorname{len}(B \setminus A) \\ &= \operatorname{len}(B).\end{aligned}$$  And since $|A| = |B|$, as noted above, we thus have $\frac{\operatorname{len}(A)}{|A|} ≤ \frac{\operatorname{len}(B)}{|B|}$ (where, again, the inequality is strict unless $A = B$).

---

**Ps.** So how do real-world [lossless compression schemes](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Lossless_compression) work, then?  Simply put, they rely on the fact that most "natural" files (containing uncompressed image or sound data, program code, text, etc.) tend to be highly repetitive and quite unlike a *random* file of similar length.  Basically, those "natural" files form only a small subset of all files of their length, and clever compression software can identify such repetitive files and shorten them, while (slightly) increasing the length of other, more random-looking input files.

It's also possible to do this in a way that is guaranteed to never increase the length of any file by more than a small fixed number of bits even in the worst case.  In fact, it's possible to take any lossless compression scheme $f$ and turn it into a scheme $f'$ that is nearly as efficient and only ever increases the length of any input file by at most one bit: simply define $$f'(x) = \begin{cases} (0, f(x)) & \text{if } \operatorname{len}(f(x)) < \operatorname{len}(x) \\ (1, x) & \text{otherwise,} \end{cases}$$ where $(b, x)$ denotes prepending the bit $b$ to the file $x$.

Comment: It is true that you cannot make a _lossless_ compression scheme this way. But the OP mentioned sending videos and images - things that don't necessarily need lossless compression. Could this make the basis of perhaps a good _lossy_ compression method for those, or would it not have any advantages to existing methods (e.g. H.264 and the like)? The idea basically seems to be using some sort of guess as to the "most probable" data, not the exact one that was actually encrypted. So we're talking about lossy compression. Nonetheless, there's still a hard limit when you bite off

Comment: enough information that your eyes start to notice.

Comment: When you say "There is no lossless compression scheme for which the average length of the output files is shorter than the average length of the input files (with averages taken over all files at most  bits long, for any non-negative integer )." I presume you mean "all possible files", rather than "all files I have on my hard drive at this moment". But there's not much value in discussing "all possible files", because 99.9% of them don't exist. Files don't contain random bits.

Comment: @The_Sympathizer, If I understand OP's question correctly, they are trying to accomplish a file format agnostic lossy compression technique. Most lossy compression techniques rely on removing information that human senses can overlook, this varies with the kind of information, so we have different techniques for different formats. A common technique might not work because you may remove a certain % of information from, lets say, audio and not notice it, but remove the same % of information from video and you might.

Comment: @syfluqs yes, the idea is that it is agnostic to what is being transferred, so there's no format-specific reduction in content, like one might have with an image optimiser. Perhaps I should have better emphasised that the idea is to rely on heavy computation at server and mobile level, and assume a low-bandwidth. We're asking the computers to create and solve puzzles, not unpack according to known instructions.

Comment: @Ilmari Karonen - thank you very much for your detailed answer, I appreciate the time it took. I will need more than the few read throughs to understand the concepts you are discussing in it, and will use it as a starting point for further research. At the risk of sounding very stupid in front of people that aren't, how conceptually does the above method differ from us solving sudokus? We fill in the missing data using maths and end the puzzle with more data than we started with. In that sense, we aren't decoding "compressed" data, we are creating new data based on rules.

Comment: @JohnnyRockex The difference is that sudokus are a *very* carefully constrained sort of system such that one only needs a few squares filled in to uniquely identify the entire puzzle.  We aren't so lucky with computer data.  The worst case scenario of a big blob of highly unpredictable data actually occurs by design in cryptography.

Comment: @CortAmmon Conceptually though, they are different in degree not kind. We could write a programme today that solves a 3x3 sudoku instantly. Tomorrow we make it a 9x9, then 100x100, 10(3), 10(4) and so on. At what point on the road to a 10k cubed sudoku do the rules for solving the puzzle fail? The ratio of known to unknown data increases (which is what we want) and more computer power/time is needed, but we're not asking it to something different, just levelling up the difficulty. The goal is to design the cube as easy as possible to solve while upping the ratio of known to unknown data.

Comment: @Johnny The difference is that in a Sudoku, the rows, columns and boxes *must* obey fixed rules, which let us solve the puzzle. A general image (or other file) isn't constrained like that. However, most useful / interesting data *does* have various kinds of patterns, and a compressor can encode that pattern info in a more compact way. The tricky part is extracting those patterns because there is no general algorithm that can do that for all possible patterns.

Comment: But it's certainly possible to create a compressor that looks for certain kinds of patterns. Thus we use different compressors for text vs images vs audio.

Comment: I expect it's possible to create a ML based compressor that's specialized at compressing cat pictures (borrowing techniques from Deep Fakes) that does significantly better than JPEG. But if you give the cat compressor a photo of a fish, it will fail miserably. ;)

Comment: @Johnny Ilmari and a few of the others have mentioned the pigeon-hole principle. This is the core principle that shows why a universal compressor cannot compress every file. The pigeon-hole principle crops up in many parts of mathematics, not just data compression, and there are numerous questions involving it on this site. If you're serious about designing compression algorithms, you *must* understand this principle.

Comment: @PM2Ring in Sudokus we know that each square must contain numbers 1-9, and we use the absence of a number like 7, to imply the rule that a 7 must exist in that square somewhere. The numbers on the reflection of the cube imply the rule that somewhere in the cube there must be binary data in that row. It is unconstrained in the sense that it could be at any coordinate at point of creation, just as a Sudoku needn't always follow the same fixed pattern.

Comment: @PM2Ring Yes, I need to look into the pigeon hole principle further, absolutely. I understand the rough outlines of it, but the fact that it keeps cropping up in answers implies there is still more to understand.

Comment: @JohnnyRockex Yes, but there are many Sudoku problems that can't be solved like you are imagining – they have multiple solutions, so there's no way to know which one is right. This is the pigeon hole principle – if there are more solutions (aka possible files in the world) than representations (your good idea for reflections), then you can't always find the right solution given a representation.

Comment: It may be useful to look at the [Mathematics of Sudoku](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Mathematics_of_Sudoku).  In particular, it's worth noting that only a tiny fraction of Latin Squares (each value appears in each row and each column) are Sudoku (each value appears in each 3x3 grid).  For a 9x9 its 0.0000012 of them that are Sudoku puzzles.  And that's when you already assume its a Latin square.  The Sudoku actually starts with quite a lot of structure that you know about from the start.  It makes the solving process doable.

Answer (score 10):

As others have pointed out, this cannot work for general reasons.

However, you may be more interested in understanding where your analysis for this specific scheme breaks down.

Consider a cube of $n^3$ bits. In each row there are $2^n$ different combinations, so if you can store $k$ values for each entry on one of the three sides, you can at best reduce the number of possibilities to $2^n/k$.

In your example for $n=1000$ and using primes, you have to and able to store not actually values up to 7919, but you to the sum of the first 1000 primes, which requires 7 decimal digits. In any case, there would be 10000000 different values to encode $2^{1000}\approx 10^{300}$ different combinations, so in the best case, one value on the side corresponds to $10^{293}$ different combinations of bits in that row. Even projecting in the different directions won't make a significant difference.

If you want to make this work, you need many more digits to store your sums, or go to a very high dimension rather than 3.
In both cases the required extra data to transmit will be equal to our exceed the original amount of data.

Comment: Thank you for your answer. To your first point - my mistake - the primes on the side of the cube are like coordinates, and the maximum possible output is the sum of those coordinates - 3682913, which is 7 digits. This would be a row full of binary ones - unlikely but possible. Where there are fewer, we don't need to transfer 7 characters. Even assuming an equal 1/0 ratio though the sum of the first 500 primes is 824693, still 6 digits, not the 4 digits I stated in the question.

Comment: On the second point, those are large numbers :P So going small to start, and ignoring the data cost, taking a Rubik's cube of 3x3x3 and randomly assigning any of the 27 cells as either on or off, each row has 8 possible combinations, right? A regular computer would eat that up - but somewhere along the way to n = 1000, it stops working - not because of any mathematical reason, but because we don't have Deep Thought in our pockets. With the caveat that I haven't fully understood the other answers yet, does this break down on concept or practice / computing power?

Comment: @JohnnyRockex I'm afraid it breaks down on concept. If you want the sum of your row to  strongly limit the number of combinations giving rise to the same sum, you need very large numbers. E.g. for each combination to give a unique sum, you cannot use fewer than $n$ bits for the sum (e.g. using the straightforward sequence 1,2,4,8,... so that the sum is simply the binary representation of the bits in that row).

Comment: @JohnnyRockex (continued) As soon as your maximum sum is smaller than that, say 100 bits for $n = 1000$ (for compression by a factor $10/3$), there will be sums that correspond to $2^{1000 - 100} \approx 10^{270}$ combinations. There is no way to identify which one by just mixing values by projection in 3 directions.

Comment: right, so we lose so much information in the sum that we cannot recover it afterwards and accurately say this bit is at that coordinate. If we were to maintain enough identifying coordinate data, the reflection would be uselessly big.

Answer (score 10):

Extrapolating from what you said, using prime numbers will *hurt* data compression, not help it.

Suppose we have a sequence of 8 bits: ($b_0, b_1, b_2, b_3, b_4, b_5, b_6, b_7$).

We could make a product of prime numbers to encode that sequence of bits: $x = 2^{b_0} × 3^{b_1} × 5^{b_2} × 7^{b_3} × 11^{b_4} × 13^{b_5} × 17^{b_6} × 19^{b_7}$.

But now the range of possible values of $x$ is $[1, 9699690]$, which would take 24 bits to represent in standard notation. This is far worse than our original 8 bits.

Products of primes can be used for theoretical math proofs though: https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/G%C3%B6del_numbering

Answer (score 1):

It's a comment, just does not fit

As one of those guys with slow connections, appreciate the efforts.

Youtube is good for me exactly because it has 144p videos, and if something is interesting or I need it I can choose which xxxp to set.

But it has its problems switching and buffering which it probably would not have if that variety of resolutions would be implemented/achieved differently.

In the good old days of modems, it was more often seen, a picture which starts as few huge pixels and then detail'es as long as more data is downloaded. Not sure which compression it was, but it looks like a jpeg on steroids. Those data chunks could be defined as n-streams for video or multiple images, and it could give a finer control on the user side, but setting a limit on how many channels to request, or adjust it automatically.

So maybe take look not in the direction of how much to compress, but how to control quality. All fixed bitrate and variable bitrate compression formats do that varying quality or attempting to keep quality. But they produce one data blob, and manage different resolutions may be challenging on the server-side, so the user does not have that many options (glad there are some places where one has), lags switching quality, etc, etc.

So maybe, as a suggestion, approach the problem from a different perspective -more flexible control of quality on user and server-side. More seamless transition from one quality to another and alike.

People on slower connections already do compromises and sure they appreciate places that offer suitable options. Same way as there is no alternative for youtube for me because the least quality I have seen was 360p and it's top-quality for me (with some difficulties, if weather is right so to speak) if they(alternatives) have such options at all. Sometimes I would not mind 100p or do not need video at all until I do, and when I do, I would like it not to discard the already existing 1min buffer but add to it to improve quality.

So better tools and options and approaches to fight all those compromises may be more appreciated than an amazing algorithm that does 10% better than all existing algorithms on any data. By varying quality I get a 90% reduction of data most of the time - when details begin to be important then yes it's time for heavy guns like waiting for a buffer and other available options.

In general, trading user resources for less data transfer is not impossible, and it is not necessarily purely a math problem - like 5 sentences describing an apple tree or a picture, and user side ai generates one or finds visually similar from a dictionary, etc. But it is a bit more vast problem.

Comment: just noticed .png still has that option of gradual detalization, this image is an example https://i.stack.imgur.com/fZzVE.png picture with text is not the best use for it but, one I noticed just now.

Comment: That's [Adam7 interlacing](https://en.m.wikipedia.org/wiki/Adam7_algorithm). Usually, the early passes are rendered as large squares, not single pixels. I've used Adam7 when writing things like fractal explorer programs because it makes it much faster to navigate.